# Unable to use pip install

Tags: python, 22.04, pip

I am getting this error when I try `pip install` for almost all modules. I tried `chime` and a couple of others too

```
pip install playsound
bash: /home/devel/.local/bin/pip: /snap/blender/2661/3.2/python/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Is it related to Blender? I uninstalled the Blender snap and is now using the Executable file. But the issue persists.

I am just trying to run a .py file and use it to play an alert sound. And it needs me to install `playsound` or similar using pip.

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Installing modules using pip from snap package is not possible. Module `playsound` installs using system's pip, but it is not visible to snap package.

```
pip install playsound
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting playsound
  Downloading playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: playsound
  Building wheel for playsound (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for playsound: filename=playsound-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=7035 sha256=9860a90d2b50bb48c9ab4c28794674b3a3694a23da9e8d08d7bccd28cc164891
  Stored in directory: /home/xubuntu/.cache/pip/wheels/90/89/ed/2d643f4226fc8c7c9156fc28abd8051e2d2c0de37ae51ac45c
Successfully built playsound
Installing collected packages: playsound
Successfully installed playsound-1.3.0
```

Try `sudo snap remove --purge yoursnap; sudo apt install python3-pip` .

Comment: To be honest, I do not know what happened. I did install Blender snap a few months ago.  As you can see, it is Blender 3.1 and the latest version is 3.3 which is months ahead. As for the purge command, when I saw this error, I used the `Ubuntu Software` to uninstall the Blender. But I can see the folder under the `Snap` folder in `Home`. It would great if I can have the exact command to use. Thanks

Comment: I got this `snap remove blender --purge
snap "blender" is not installed
`

Comment: sudo apt install python3-pip worked. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Corrected the answer.

Comment: In cases like this you may also try `python -m pip ...` or `python3 -m pip ...`